# How can i bulk change sku

Tags: magento, sku

I need to change my products sku, actually, my site consists 20k products, how can I bulk change my SKU's by CSV format. Is it possible by CSV format?

Comment: yes, you can do that by CSV. change in CSV and import products method of magento

Comment: may i know csv header column which is useful for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @urfusion : May i know the columns in csv

Comment: https://trellis.co/blog/uploading-products-magento-product-excel/

Comment: http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/2012/11/magento-raw-product-import-csv-creation/

Comment: @urfusion: Already my products inside the site with the wrong SKU, so I need to replaced by original sku, how can I replaced by CSV. May i know the required columns name of csv.

Comment: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-edit-product-prices-through-the-external-csv-file.html#gref

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to bulk update products.

1. Export CSV with the required fields which you needs to update and change data and import that.
2. There is a tool "MAGMI Importer" for magento bulk update.

Comment: I tried multiple combinations, but not working. If you know pls share CSV demo file for bulk change sku by original sku.